# Trying to pass lines of a text file to a command as an argument

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I'm doing this in the git command line for Windows (gitbash?) so that may be causing problems (Windows does not now what a line feed is).

Trying to pass paths in a file to git the following way:

```
$ while read p; do   git checkout dev $p; done <test.txt
' did not match any file(s) known to git.
' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

File paths are fine so I'm not sure what the problem is here

```
$ while read p; do   echo $p; done <test.txt
one.txt
two.txt
```

The command: `git checkout dev one.txt` has no error.

Comment: Maybe special characters in your test.txt. You can check with `cat -A test.txt`

Comment: Look especially for carriage returns

Comment: Waht does `echo "git checkout dev [$p]"` show?

Comment: @WalterA I used that to create a text file with the commands: `while read p; do echo "git checkout dev \"$p\""; done <test.txt > commands.txt` Then I just copy paste the content of commands.txt to the command line.

Comment: Does `. ./commands.txt` work?

Comment: Have you tried with a xargs ? `<text.txt xargs -I % git checkout dev %`

Comment: Try: while read line; do newLine=$(echo $line | cut -d$'\n' -f 1); git checkout dev $newLine; done < file.txt . If it does not work try by replacing the \n by \r.